# Splitting a line of text that has key value pairs where value can be empty

Tags: c#, regex

I need to split a line of text

1. The general syntax for a delivery instruction is |||name|value||name|value||…..|||
2. Each delivery instruction starts and ends with 3 pipe characters - |||
3. A delivery instruction is a set of name/value pairs separated by a single pipe eg name|value
4. Each name value pair is separated by 2 pipe characters ||
5. Names and Values may not contain the pipe character
6. The value of any pair may be a blank string.

I need a regex that will help me resolve the above problem.

My latest attempt with my limited Regex skills:

```
string SampleData = "|||env|af245g||mail_idx|39||gen_date|2016/01/03 11:40:06||docm_name|Client Statement (01.03.2015−31.03.2015)||docm_cat_name|Client Statement||docm_type_id|9100||docm_type_name|Client Statement||addr_type_id|1||addr_type_name|Postal address||addr_street_nr|||addr_street_name|Robinson Road||addr_po_box|||addr_po_box_type|||addr_postcode|903334||addr_city|Singapore||addr_state|||addr_country_id|29955||addr_country_name|Singapore||obj_nr|10000023||bp_custr_type|Customer||access_portal|Y||access_library|Y||avsr_team_id|13056||pri_avsr_id|||pri_avsr_name|||ctact_phone|||dlv_type_id|5001||dlv_type_name|Channel to standard mail||ao_id|14387||ao_name|Corp Limited||ao_title|||ao_mob_nr|||ao_email_addr||||??";
string[] Split = Regex.Matches(SampleData, "(\|\|\|(?:\w+\|\w*\|\|)*\|)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

The expected output should be as follows(based on the sample data string provided):

1. env|af245g
2. mail_idx|39
3. gen_date|2016/01/03 11:40:06
4. docm_name|Client Statement (01.03.2015−31.03.2015)
5. docm_cat_name|Client Statement
6. docm_type_id|9100
7. docm_type_name|Client Statement
8. addr_type_id|1
9. addr_type_name|Postal address
10. addr_street_nr|
11. addr_street_name|Robinson Road
12. addr_po_box|
13. addr_po_box_type|
14. addr_postcode|903334
15. addr_city|Singapore
16. addr_state|
17. addr_country_id|29955
18. addr_country_name|Singapore
19. obj_nr|10000023
20. bp_custr_type|Customer
21. access_portal|Y
22. access_library|Y
23. avsr_team_id|13056
24. pri_avsr_id|
25. pri_avsr_name|
26. ctact_phone|
27. dlv_type_id|5001
28. dlv_type_name|Channel to standard mail
29. ao_id|14387
30. ao_name|Corp Limited
31. ao_title|
32. ao_mob_nr|
33. ao_email_addr|

Comment: is it must for you to use Regex? i means it can be solved easily using c# split method!

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: I agree with @SyedMuhammadZeeshan RegEx seems overkill for something like this. A simple split and/or just a loop over the string seems easier.

Comment: I know using a regex might not be the best fit for this scenario however this is just a snippet of code that fits into a more generic component that we have. Hence the need for a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're making this more difficult than it needs to be.  This regex yields the desired result:

```
@"[^|]+\|([^|]*)"
```

Assuming you're dealing with a single, well-formed delivery instruction, there's no need to match the starting and ending triple-pipes.  You don't need to worry about the double-pipe separators either, because the "name" part of the "name|value" pair is always present.  Just look for the first thing that looks like a name with a pipe following it, and everything up to the next pipe character is the value.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do it without using Regex. Its just simple splitting.

```
    string nameValues = "|||zeeshan|1||ali|2||ahsan|3|||";
    string sub = nameValues.Substring(3, nameValues.Length - 6);
    Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string[] subsub = sub.Split(new string[] {"||"}, StringSplitOptions.None);

    foreach (string item in subsub)
    {
        string[] nameVal = item.Split('|');
        dic.Add(nameVal[0], nameVal[1]);
    }

    foreach (var item in dic)
    {
        // Retrieve key and value here i.e:
        // item.Key
        // item.Value
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: A good, simple solution. Your answer works and does the job well. I'd like to give you the points since your answer works but it does not use a regex.

Comment: yes as I already mentioned that its the solution without using Regex.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=\|\|\|).*?(?=\|\|\|)
```

You can use this to get all the `key value pairs` between `|||`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/59

```
string strRegex = @"(?<=\|\|\|).*?(?=\|\|\|)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
string strTargetString = @"|||env|af245g||mail_idx|39||gen_date|2016/01/03 11:40:06||docm_name|Client Statement (01.03.2015−31.03.2015)||docm_cat_name|Client Statement||docm_type_id|9100||docm_type_name|Client Statement||addr_type_id|1||addr_type_name|Postal address||addr_street_nr|||addr_street_name|Robinson Road||addr_po_box|||addr_po_box_type|||addr_postcode|903334||addr_city|Singapore||addr_state|||addr_country_id|29955||addr_country_name|Singapore||obj_nr|10000023||bp_custr_type|Customer||access_portal|Y||access_library|Y||avsr_team_id|13056||pri_avsr_id|||pri_avsr_name|||ctact_phone|||dlv_type_id|5001||dlv_type_name|Channel to standard mail||ao_id|14387||ao_name|Corp Limited||ao_title|||ao_mob_nr|||ao_email_addr||||??";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
   if (myMatch.Success)
   {
     // Add your code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation of @Syed Muhammad Zeeshan  code that runs faster:

```
string nameValues = "|||zeeshan|1||ali|2||ahsan|3|||";
            string[] nameArray = nameValues.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (string item in nameArray)
            {
                if (i < nameArray.Length - 1)
                    dic.Add(nameArray[i], nameArray[i + 1]);
                i = i + 2;
            }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this code will work in all cases. There are empty values and you remove all empty items. If you change `||ali|2||` to `||ali|||` I think is will break your indexes.

Comment: Yup, I wrote it to demonstrate a variation of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I will like to try:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string nameValueList = "|||zeeshan|1||ali|2||ahsan|3|||";
        while (nameValueList != "|||")
        {
            nameValueList = nameValueList.TrimStart('|');
            string nameValue = GetNameValue(ref nameValueList);
            Console.WriteLine(nameValue);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string GetNameValue(ref string nameValues)
    {
        string retVal = string.Empty;
        while(nameValues[0] != '|') // for name
        {
            retVal += nameValues[0];
            nameValues = nameValues.Remove(0, 1);
        }

        retVal += nameValues[0];
        nameValues = nameValues.Remove(0, 1);

        while (nameValues[0] != '|') // for value
        {
            retVal += nameValues[0];
            nameValues = nameValues.Remove(0, 1);
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/WRbsRu